# Regular Expressions - matching words which meet the condition

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, regex-negation

I have a problem to solve:

I need to match every word which has less than 4 characters expect word i,j,k and pom.I made reg exp which finds all words where the size is less than 4  - [a-zA-Z]{1,3} but i dont know how to exclude i,j,k and pom. And i need to do it in one reg exp.

Thanks a lot for the  answers

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @SLePort he means characters i and j and k should pass the regex, while they are less than 4.

Comment: Input:

int i = 5;
int pom = 1;
char var = 'a';
int hello = 0;
bool hey = true;

And output should be (what should reg exp match is):
char var = 'a';
bool hey = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***updated***
`(?i)\b(?!pom|[ijk]\b)[a-z]{1,3}\b`

```
 (?i)                     # Inline modifier, case-insensitive
 \b                       # word boundary
 (?! pom | [ijk] \b )     # Assert not 'pom' nor single i, j or k
 [a-z]{1,3}               # 1 to 3 letters a-z
 \b                       # word boundary
```

Comment: Depends on what OP means by excluding "i,j,k". I took this literally in my answer....

Comment: This reg exps doesnt match 
jjj or iji but it should, it shouldnt match j but it should match jj, just single character 'j' and 'k' and 'j' should exclude.

thanks

Comment: @anticol - I see. Updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
$ cat b.txt
abcdef
abcd
abc
pom.
pom
i,j,k

$ grep -E '^([a-z]{1,3}|pom.|i,j,k)$' b.txt
abc
pom.
pom
i,j,k
```

Remarks:
* Test above matches lines, you can modify it like `-E -w -o` to match words in line
* Word `pom` will be matched by default since it has length three=less than 4
* Word `pom.` (ending in dot) would have been excluded, but it is saved due to regex or operation (symbol `|`)

Update

```
$ grep -E '^([a-z]{1,3}|pom.|i|j|k)$' b.txt
```

Comment: I am sorry maybe my question was not clear but i dont mean string "i,j,k" but characters separately 'i', 'j' and 'k'

Comment: @anticol Try the updated regex

Comment: this will match input 'i' and i dont want that

Comment: @anticol then ` i {2,3}`???